# How to make buttons/elements animate when hovering across them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have an example of what I'm thinking of as I can't really describe it, I hope people won't mind me putting a direct link to a commercial website but anyway:

https://www.bladux.com/shared-hosting

Near the bottom theres a segment with 6 div elements that animate in similar ways when you hover over each one.

At first I suspected that onmouseenter the still background images were being replaced with GIFs but then I realised that onmouseleave was somehow "reversing" the animation from the point at which the animation had completed when onmouseleave occurred.

I'd love to know from a technical standpoint how someone goes about doing this, I don't need any specifics or examples. I just can't think of anything past GIFs.

Comment: This is pure CSS with rotating effects on hover on hover out. You can find the logic behind by searching "rotate" here: https://www.bladux.com/main/css/main.min.css

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way to handle animations is with pure CSS, so that you don't bog down your Javascript code with styling logic unnecessarily. From my experience, if you can handle these things in CSS, that's usually the best solution.

[Here's an example](http://jsbin.com/getukapupu/edit?html,css,output) of how to implement the basic effect that you're trying to accomplish.

The key elements to notice here are the transforms and transitions. No JS necessary.

Comment: Very useful, I hadn't thought of this at all. Now I just need to go and expand on this for more advanced things that I'm thinking of. Also useful to know that CSS allows adding &:hover, should help to clean up files in the future! Thanks a bunch

Comment: @PaulMcGlinchey note that the &:hover is actually a feature of Sass. `&` represents the nearest selector in the nesting (i.e. the parent). If you're using vanilla CSS, be sure to replace `&`. Otherwise, just use Sass; it's great. Also, if this answer helped you, mark is as correct.